# Как как определить сколько дней прошло с указано даты в JS

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Добрый день подскажите как определить сколько дней прошло с указанной даты до настоящего момента?, я написан небольшой код но он как то не корректно считает

```
const date = '2019-09-29T00:00:00.000Z'
// текшая дата в мс - указанная дата в мс / 1000 мс / 60 с / 60 м / 24 ч / 365 д
const res = (Date.now() - Date.parse(date)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const date = '2019-09-29T00:00:00.000Z'
let currentDate = Date.parse(new Date());
let days = (currentDate - Date.parse(date))/86400000;       //86400000 - ms в дне
console.log(Math.round(days))
```